# Over an artinian ring every nonzero module has a simple submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian, artinian

I want to prove this :

> Over an artinian ring every nonzero module has a simple submodule.

But the same statement for Noetherian rings is not true.

Is there any hint how to show that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we can assume that the module is finitely generated (just pick a finitely generated submodule).

A finitely generated module over an Artinian ring is itself Artinian. In particular, every descending chain of submodules stabilises.

So if you didn't have a simple submodule, every submodule has a proper non-trival submodule, leading to an infinite strictly descending chain. This would contradict the module being Artinian.

Comment: Alternatively to the contradiction approach in the last paragraph, you could say "the poset of nonzero submodules is nonempty and artinian, so it contains a minimal elements.

Comment: @Josh Hunt thanks,do u have any counterexample for Noetherian rings?

Comment: A good first step would be to find a ring that is noetherian but not artinian! The standard example provides a counterexample (as a module over itself) to your question

Comment: And does $\mathbb Z$ have a simple submodule?

Comment: @JoshHunt sorry!it doesn't!